# At what efficiency does a fan cool a PC case?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, airflow

A PC case is basically a rectangular pathaway for air to flow through but at the places where the air enters and exits there are solid plastic or metal panels commonly with meshes and little holes.

[image]

When a fan is rated at 50cfm or 80m3/h at 100% speed by how much is this figure decreased when taking into account the characteristics of the volume of the case?

Is it 20% or 80% for example?

Comment: The *volume* of the case will have nothing to do with the airflow. The resistance to airflow will and this will typically be determined by the minimum cross-sectional area of the airflow path. For a given airflow rate the volume of the case will determine the number of air changes per unit time. Can you reformulate your question?

Comment: What is the minimum cross-sectional area of the airflow path? How can I look this up or estimate it? What is the number of air changes per minute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When a fan is rated at 50cfm or 80 m<sup>3</sup>/h at 100% speed by how much is this figure decreased when taking into account the characteristics of the volume of the case?
>
> Is it 20% or 80% for example?

The volume of the case will have nothing to do with the airflow. The resistance to airflow will and this will typically be determined by the minimum cross-sectional area of the airflow path.

> What is the minimum cross-sectional area of the airflow path?

If it's not given you would have to work it out by measurement.

For a given airflow rate the volume of the case will determine the number of air changes per unit time.

> What is the number of air changes per minute?

If the volume of the cabinet is, for example, 0.5 m<sup>3</sup> and the airflow is 80 m<sup>3</sup>/h then the number of air changes per hour will be given by $ n = \frac f v   = \frac {80}{0.5} = 160 $ (where *f* is the airflow and *v* is the volume. 160 changes per hour is almost 3 changes per minute.

Any filters or blockages will reduce the airflow.

Comment: What is the formula for resistance affecting airflow?

Comment: https://www.engineerlive.com/content/design-system-cooling-using-dc-axial-fans

Comment: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35665/why-does-higher-density-decrease-the-airflow-requirement-for-cooling-a-pc-system

Comment: Also, how are you that good at finding these kind of answers? Do you use Google?

Comment: Most of it is basic understanding of physics. I'm an electrical engineer working in industrial automation so I get paid to think about stuff - although this question is outside my normal work. Everything in my answer should be fairly obvious now that you've thought about it. I didn't have to look that up. The article I linked in the comments I found searching for "practical calculation for axial fan and airflow". Read, think, read, think, read, ...